# How to use multiple GitHub projects in one Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, github

So I have a GitHub repo and I want to supplement it with other projects in other repos. I am using Eclipse and Java as my dev tools. Is there a video I can watch or a tutorial? I've looked on YouTube and Googled the problem -- I'm probably not building a proper query so find what I need.

I don't want to merge two repos into one repo. I want to incorporate the code in another repo into an Eclipse project on my dev machine that uses one of my repos. I think.

Comment: You'd do a great service to yourself if you spent some quality time with Google. I can see that the biggest problem of the younger generation seems to be that they don't know how to look for information. You can't expect other people to be holding your hand all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: Also, tutorial requests are off-topic.

Comment: Do you wish to use other projects as dependencies for your project?

Comment: @Kayaman I'll get off your lawn.

Comment: Have you looked into build tools (e.g. Maven, Gradle)? They let you specify which projects you want to depend on. During build time, these projects are added to your class path.

Comment: @IndrekOts I will do that, thank you. As soon as I get off Kayman's lawn.

Comment: @nicomp I don't have a lawn. I meant that as genuine advice to you. You may not like it (and the tone may have not been the nicest), but can you dismiss an experienced developer's suggestion?

Comment: @Kayaman I have no doubt you are sincere.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you wish to use other projects/libraries in your project. You should look into Java build tools (ev. Maven, Gradle and others). Among other things, they let you specify a list of dependencies for your project.

**Maven example**

First of all, you should set up your project to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

For instance, if you wish to use [joda-time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) (a popular date and time library for Java), you could go to http://mvnrepository.com/ and look for joda-time. From there select your desired version and copy-paste the Maven dependency to your `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
          <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.1</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now when you call `mvn clean install` from your commandline or use the Maven Eclipse plugin, your project is built and the dependencies you specified are downloaded and added to your class path.

Keep in mind, the source code for the dependencies is never added to your project, only the `jar` files are added to your class path.